# Экспорт table в xls

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xls

Есть таблица, нужно средствами js сделать экспорт в xls(xlsx).

```
function Excel(table, name, filename){
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            window.location.download = filename;
        }
```

нашел такой скрипт. Но при тестах обнаружилось две проблемы в xls не распознает русскую раскладку, и при сохранении файла не получается дать ему название, скачивается только неизвестный документ.

Просьба: помогите пожалуйста с этими двумя проблемами или просветите о другом способе, но только средствами js. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: чтобы файл открывать в экселе, достаточно формата csv. Ну это реально проще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
window.location.download = filename;
```

Используйте

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = "filename.xls";
link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
link.click();
```

Ну а чтобы с русскими символами проблем не было, можно или открывать файл в OpenOffice, ну или саму страницу делать в cp1251.